# Conflict of two report wars in one jboss?

Tags: deployment, birt

I have two individual report wars(say it as **A.war** & **B.war**) and deployed successfully in jboss4.x and those two wars contains their individual reports.When i tried to run a report from **B.war** it throws some exceptions that the corresponding reports doesn't exists in **A.war** that means it looking the report in **A.war** instead of that **B.war**.
Thanks

Comment: what is the path you are using to call the report

Comment: http://localhost/Testreport/frameset?__report=history.rptdesign. here Testreport is the context root for the B.war

http://localhost/llopreport/frameset?__report=rental.rptdesign. here llopreport is the context root for the A.war

Comment: Both wars are deployed in \\Tools\myyjboss-.0.5.GA\server\default\deploy

Comment: try using the absolute path e.g. /usr/local/jboss/server/default/deploy/B.war/frameset?__report=history.rptdesign and see if it works

Comment: will try and tell u ? but is it a good way to call the report through the absolute path ?

Comment: You mean there is a webviewer and a birt engine within each WAR?

Comment: To avoid any confusion, make sure you explicitly set in web.xml of each .war,properties such BIRT_VIEWER_WORKING_FOLDER, BIRT_RESOURCE_PATH, BIRT_VIEWER_DOCUMENT_FOLDER.  See properties list and description [here]http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage2.2.php